# Find unbiased estimator for a and b based on X and Y

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator

I need help with the following question (sorry for not formatting, I do not know how):
$X$ and $Y$ are random variables, each have standard deviation of 3. The Pearson correlation equals to 0.6 (in this case the correlation is of the probability meaning $(\operatorname{cov}(x,y)/\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X) \operatorname{var}(Y)}.$
$\operatorname{E}[X]=a+b, \operatorname{E}[Y] = a-b$.

Find unbiased estimators for $a$ and $b$ based on $X$ and $Y$.

So far I have placed the data, and got to $1.8=\operatorname{E}[XY]-(a*a)+b(*b)$ but I have no idea how to go on.

Comment: If you have $E[X]=a+b$, $E[Y] = a-b$, and ignoring all the other detail,  then in what sense are the obvious estimators $\hat a=\frac12(\bar X +\bar Y)$ and $\hat b=\frac12(\bar X -\bar Y)$ biased?

Comment: It is a very good solution. Though it makes me wonder why the professor gave such exercise.

Comment: I suspect they wish you to compute the standard errors of those estimates, too: that's part of what it means to "find" an estimator.